# Fetching the wrong amount in database using SELECT DISTINCT COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am tracking when sellers sell below a certain price on a product on Amazon. I am storing products, sellers, and violations in the database. I am attempting to display the number of sellers who are violating within a 24 hour period. Rather than displaying the number of sellers violating, I am receiving the total number of violations.

ViolationsRepository.php

```
public function countNumberOfSellersInViolationsForVendorInLast24Hours($vendorId)
{
    $select = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(
        CASE
        WHEN v.source = 'amazon' THEN
          (SELECT DISTINCT s.id
           FROM seller_info_amazon AS sai
             LEFT JOIN sellers_amazon AS sa ON sa.amazon_id = sai.id
             LEFT JOIN sellers AS s ON sa.seller_id = s.id
           WHERE sai.unique_id = v.seller_id_amazon AND s.id IS NOT NULL
           LIMIT 1)
        WHEN v.source = 'ebay' THEN
          (SELECT s.id
           FROM sellers AS s
           WHERE s.id = v.seller_id_ebay
           LIMIT 1)
        WHEN v.source = 'google' THEN
          (SELECT s.id
           FROM sellers AS s
           WHERE s.id = v.seller_id_google
           LIMIT 1)
        END)
    FROM
      violations AS v

    ";

    $timeLimit = new \DateTime('24 hours ago');

    $where = " WHERE v.vendor_id = :vendorId AND v.last_scout_date >= :timeLimit \n";


    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($select . $where );
    $query->bindValue(':vendorId', $vendorId);
    $query->bindValue(':timeLimit', $timeLimit->format("Y-m-d h:i:s"));

    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchColumn();

}
```

**sellers_amazon TABLE**

```
seller_id   amazon_id
```

**violations TABLE**

```
id      vendor_id   seller_id_amazon    last_scout_date source
```

**seller_info_amazon TABLE**

```
id  unique_id   name
```

**sellers TABLE**

```
id   originating_vendor_id   name
```

Comment: show your database tables structure

Comment: @CodeGodie updated

Answer (score 0):

Solved this -  `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT( ...`.